# Effects of profiler itself on performance measurement in .Net

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, performance, profiler, performance-testing

What are the effects of running, say, the Visual Studio 2010 profiler on the performance of my program?  That is, in what ways are the results from a profiler actually inaccurate due to how the profiler has to "interfere" with the program's normal operation to check the performance?  Or are there any such issues?

This question stems from the fact that I'm seeing property gets/sets as taking up significant amounts of time in my methods in the Visual Studio 2010 profiler (I program in C#).  These properties are the ones that are automatically generated by a .resx Resource Dictionary (avoiding magic strings :-) ), and so I would *assume* that the JIT compiler and/or the interpreter running behind the scenes *generally* would inline them if it would be helpful.  I would presume though that such inlining doesn't happen when you are running the profiler...  Or does it?

I am specifically working with the Visual Studio 2010 profiler, but I would appreciate an answer that includes other profilers.

Sorry if I have missed a question that answers this already- feel free to point the way.

Comment: Properties are indeed expensive and take about 80 times more time than public fields. It also seems like they are not optimized away (not even by nGen). In areas where inheritance and interoperability do not play any role, I often use public fields instead of properties to boost performance (if the team allows it, some developers get religious about this 'sin'). I have a sneaking suspicion that properties do get optimized away in virtual machines with Hyper-V technology. Somehow things perform significantly better in the virtual machine compared to the dry OS-installation on the same hardware.

Comment: I guess it depends on the property: http://www.dotnetperls.com/property.   Some are apparently optimized away.  But it appears that, as a conclusion to what @Cydermaxs has said, that instrumentation could very well prevent properties from being optimized, simply by means of measuring their speed. The same may happen for sampling, but that is unsure at this point.

Comment: IMHO (and after seeing the answer below), only using Timer to compare optimized code against optimized code would work for determining whether properties or fields are faster in your specific instance.

Comment: Side note: I discovered that the properties generated by resx dictionaries have a (what do you know) Dictionary "get" call inside of them, which make them rather more expensive than local fields in high-use scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, it depends ...

As you may know, there are many profiling modes. For CPU/time profiling, trere are Sampling and Instrumentation.

Sample profiling is more “statistical” profiling. The accuracy of the results is dependant on number of times the code executes during the profiling session. At regular intervals the Profiler takes a snapshot of the call stack of each thread executing on the target the process(es). If a Method has a huge number of samples, it can be because of many execution or long method execution. It is very lightweight and has minimal performance impact on the system, and is easy to use.

This instrumentation involves inserting probes into the target code at the start and end of each function being instrumented, so that the entry into and exit from every function call can be tracked. In a profiling session, the exact number of times a function is called and how long it takes to execute can be exactly measured. However, capturing this detail comes at a cost. There is a fairly significant processing overhead being introduced on every function call (usually at least 10% and can easily be 100% or more, but is more or less dependent on the size of the functions being profiled). The increase in code size and execution of additional code in the profiler can also cause some adverse CPU caching effects.

The last important thing to understand is that Profiling can be view as scientific approach because you should measure your code in a real conditions (or real use cases) to find out exactly where the bottlenecks are and fix them knowing it will improve the performance.

Comment: Just to clarify, for the sampling profiling, then, what precisely is being counted?  Number of lines of code executed?  Number of times the profiler catches the code executing the specific method?  Number of times a method is called?  This isn't clear to me in the VS documentation.

Comment: As I said,  every 10 million clock cycles (default), the Profiler takes a snapshot of the *call stack* of each thread executing. It is not instrusive (no probes). It can be viewed as statistical analysis of many call stacks. There is also a distinction between an inclusive (samples including the time spent in function called from that function) or an exclusive (samples excluding the time spent in functions called from that function.